# Set Android NDK globally in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

The current version (1.2.1.1) of Android Studio allows me to build sample apps using the NDK, but I have noticed that each time I load a new project, I must set `ndk.dir=/path/to/ndk/install` in my `local.properties` file for Gradle to detect the NDK, whereas the sdk path is auto-populated.

Is there a way to set this globally via a preference or ENV variable? I could not find any indication that there is

Comment: I thought the ndk was meant for AS 1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` to the location of your SDK and `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` to the location of your NDK, *and* delete any `local.properties` file, this builds projects with native code as expected on my Android Studio 1.2. I don't know why gradle clears other property setting mechanisms when a `local.properties` file is present.

An alternative to this would be to replace the `local.properties` file with a link to a master properties file.

Note that this may all be changing when the new native code support arrives in Android Studio 1.3.

Answer (score 4):

in the latest release of **android studio 1.3** you can set NDK path directly

in windows press **ctrl+shift+alt+s** which will open project properties where you can find first option named **SDK Location** click on it and there you can see space where you can add **NDK location**